# Converting a CSV file into appropriate XML format

Tags: xml, powershell, csv

I'm trying to get some tab-delimited CSV files into an XML via PowerShell, and I'm struggling to make sense of it all. I'm 100% sure it's something really simple I'm missing, so help would be massively appreciated. I'm very close but just can't get over the final hurdle.

I essentially want this script to iterate through a tab-delimited CSV it's pointed at (`$path`), take each line off of the CSV and put the data into an XML sheet (`$xmlpath`).

CSV example:

```
"Name"  "Item"  "Purchase Price"
"Jimmy Smits"   "Egg"   "£40"
"Edward Price"  "KumQuat"   "£6000"
"Timmy Mallet"  "Bug"   "£2"
"Edgar Allen Poe"   "Weird" "0"
"2Pac Shakur"   "Eggnog"    ""
```

XML output template example:

```xml
<registration>
    <Individual>
        <Name></Name>
        <Item></Item>
        <Purchase Price></Purchase Price>
    </Individual>
</registration>
```

And this is what I've been poking about with

```
$data = Import-Csv -Path $path -Delimiter "`t"

$xmlnames = $data | Select-Object "Name"
$xmlitems = $data | Select-Object "Item"
$xmlprice = $data | Select-Object "Purchase Price"

$entryTemplate = @'
<individual>
    <Name>$($xmlnames.Name)</Name>
    <Item>$($xmlitems.Item)</Item>
    <Purchase Price>$($xmlprice."Purchase Price")</Purchase Price>
</individual>
'@

$xml = $data | ForEach-Object {
    $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($entrytemplate)
}
$xml | Out-File $xmlpath
```

Which then puts out;

```xml
<Individual>
    <Name>Jimmy Smits Edward Price Timmy Mallet Edgar Allen Poe 2Pac Shakur</Name>
    <Item>System.Object IList.Item(int index) {get;set;}</Item>
    <Purchase Price>£40 £6000 £2 0 </Purchase Price>
</Individual>
```

So somewhere I'm messing up stupidly on two things;

1. The `$data | Select-Object  'thing'` is giving me all of the list of 'things' rather than iterating through each of the 'things' and listing them one per XML entry. Yet is giving me the correct number of entries?
2. My 'Items' are being listed as system objects (not values), despite being treated identically to everything else.

Comment: when you type $data[0] ...it should output the first row of the csv...if not, the csv is not well-formed... make sure it is actually a csv file. Then proceed with other steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three statements

```
$xmlnames = $data | Select-Object "Name"
$xmlitems = $data | Select-Object "Item"
$xmlprice = $data | Select-Object "Purchase Price"
```

give you lists of custom objects with just one property. Using these lists in your template inserts *all* values into a tag with each iteration. What you want is just the value from the current iteration, hence creating the lists before doesn't do you any good. What you actually want is the current object during each iteration of the loop.

In case of `$xmlitems` you're also running into a PowerShell gotcha, because the variables `$xmlnames`, `$xmlitems`, and `$xmlprice` are arrays. When using dot-access on an array PowerShell is doing something that is called [member enumeration](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/new-v3-language-features/). Essentially `$xmlnames.Name` won't give you the value of the property `Name` of the *array* object, but the value of the property `Name` of all array *elements*.

Member enumeration only works if the array object itself doesn't have a member of that name, though. Which brings us back to `$xmlitems`. For that variable you're trying to get the value of the property `Item` of the array elements. However, the array object actually has a method `Item()`, so `$xmlitems.Item` tries to invoke that method instead of the `Item` property of the array elements. But since the method is overloaded and the invocation is missing parentheses (`$xmlitems.Item` instead of `$xmlitems.Item()`) PowerShell shows you the method definition instead.

Remove the `Select-Object` statements and replace the array variables in your XML fragment template with the ["current object" variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-3.0#_) `$_` and the code will do what you want.

```
$entryTemplate = @'
<individual>
    <Name>$($_.Name)</Name>
    <Item>$($_.Item)</Item>
    <Purchase Price>$($_."Purchase Price")</Purchase Price>
</individual>
'@
```

Comment: 'Doh' of course!

I was sure the select-objects were causing the multiple selections, but I couldn't wrap my head around the methods/arrays. Thanks for taking the time to explain it properly for me, this is now working perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use "LINQ to XML" to create xml.

```
using namespace "System.Xml.Linq"
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Xml.Linq

[XElement]::new("registration", @(
    Import-Csv -Path $path -Delimiter "`t" | foreach {
        [XElement]::new("Individual",
            [XElement]::new("Name", $_.Name),
            [XElement]::new("Item", $_.Item),
            [XElement]::new("PurchasePrice", $_."Purchase Price"))
    }
)).Save($xmlpath)
```